# I'm facing spacing irregularities

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: How do I fix this spacing irregularity? There's a visible difference between those blue and red marked spaces.]
How do I fix this spacing irregularity? There's a visible difference between those blue and red marked spaces.
Can anyone help me out there?
Thank you

Comment: What justification do you have set?

Comment: Justify with last line aligned left.

Comment: If you are not a professional designer I would recommend never to use justified text. Go with left aligned, almost always looks better and is much easier to typeset...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select all the text.
2. In the Paragaph panel make sure you use "Justify with last line aligned left". It can really mess things up if you choose the "Justify all lines" option especially at the bottom of paragraphs.

[image]

3. Click the tiny menu icon at the top right of the panel, and choose "Justification" to open up the settings.
4. Change the letter spacing values to allow a little letter spacing. That will help eliminate those big gaps between words. I set Desired 5%, and Maximum 20%, but you can dial in what you'd prefer.

Example showing similar problem with the second line, and the preview of the fix.

[image]

Note: You might also want to enable hyphenation, because that can cause similar problems too if you don't, especially if there are any long words in a relatively narrow column/paragraph. Hyphenation settings are also in the Paragraph panel menu.

[image]